# OPEN ACC - how to handle data management of Struct inside routines?

Tags: loops, struct, openacc, data-management

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct Data_{
  double **v;   
  .
  .
  .
  double *press; 
}Data;
```

In the main function, I have a while loop, inside of which it's called a routine in which is declared data, and I use the following pragma:

```
static Data data;
#pragma acc enter data copyin(data[:7])
```

In this routine, it's called another one ( `RHS (&data, ...)` ).
Again, inside of the latter I call another routine( `RHS1(data,...)` ), in which there's the loop I want to accelerate:

```
#pragma acc parallel loop present(data[:7])
  for (i = beg; i <= end; i++) {
    rhs[i][MX1] += dt*data->src[i][MX1];
    . += .
    . += .
    . += .
    . += .
    . += .
    rhs[i][ENG] += dt*sweep->src[i][ENG];
  }
```

I get this error compiling with -managed:
**FATAL ERROR: variable in data clause is partially present on the device: name=data**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues here.

```
#pragma acc enter data copyin(data[:7])
```

This is saying that you want to copyin an array of 7 "data" structures, not a structure of with 7 members.  Change this to be:

```
#pragma acc enter data copyin(data)
```

The compiler knows the size of the struct and will allocate the appropriate size in the device copy.

However, copy clauses only perform a shallow copy of the structure.  So here you're copying the host pointers of the data members to the device and accessing "src" would give you an illegal address error.  So you'll need to take the extra step of doing a manual deep copy of all the members that will be used on the device.

So later in the program, after you've allocated "src", add an additional directive:

```
#pragma acc enter data copyin(data.src[0:nx][0:ny])
```

(change nx and ny to the actual size variables of the dimensions)

This will first create the "src" array on the device and then "attach" the device src to the device copy of data.  "attach" basically fills in the value of the device "data.src" to the address of the device src array.

Then on your parallel loop, use just "present(data)".

Note that if you use the update directive to synchronize data, be sure to only update "src" and not "data".  Again, this would perform a shallow copy so updating data would be copying host/device pointers, which would cause runtime errors.

I wrote a basic example on how to do this as part of Chapter 5 of the book *Parallel Programming with OpenACC* with an example that you can find at: https://github.com/rmfarber/ParallelProgrammingWithOpenACC/blob/master/Chapter05/array_of_structs.c